# How to redirect to mobile site for specific range of android versions

Tags: redirect

I would like to redirect site to mobile version only for android versions below a certain build, specifically below Ice Cream Sandwich, that is API level 14

I am able to at present only redirect for a certain build and unable to redirect for a range of builds. Please suggest how to redirect for a range of builds.

This is the code which I am using -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android 4.2.2') != -1) ) {
    document.location = "http://www.yoururladdress.com/yourpage.html";
} // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to this question.

Code is as follows -

```
<script>
<!--

var str = navigator.userAgent ;
var version = str.match(/Android\s+([\d\.]+)/)[1];
var version = version.substring(0, 3);

if(version <= 4.0)
location.replace("http://www.yoururladdress.com/yourpage.html");

}
-->

</script>
```